# Entity Framework in user control error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF for my LiveCharts inside a user control but I'm getting an error

> No connection string named 'KiculoServerEntities' could be found in the application config file.

I managed to fix it once after I deleted and create a new EF but after I restarted VS this error showed again,

```
<add name="KiculoServerEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/KiculoCraftModel.csdl|res://*/KiculoCraftModel.ssdl|res://*/KiculoCraftModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-1281SGB;initial catalog=KiculoServer;persist security info=True;user id=KicuCrafts;password=admin;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that your connection string at same project with your startup project ? If you have more then one project at same solution you may forgot write connection string at final project that you call entity framework objects.

Comment: ^^ That's a good point.  Have you added the connection string to the app.config for the application that uses the user control, and not just the user control itself?

Comment: @nzrytmn no, I only have one project.

Comment: Can you add code referencing to the connection string? Is it a web app? Add all relevant information about the project please.

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto I'm using winforms

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to put that line under:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
      <!-- here put your connection string -->
  </connectionStrings>
...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection String Must be available in Caller Project for e.g. If you have Project A and B. Where A is UI and B is EF project, make sure you have Connection String in Project A too

Or if you can shared Context Class and How did u call it in a project like using Startup.cs